# Checkbox value to php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the following bit of code to ensure that at least one of the checkboxes is checked, it outputs the ‘value’ of the checked box to an ID called ‘cont’. I am looking for a way to get the output into an array (PHP) instead. I'm not very good at JS.

```
<?php
$count = '0';
while($count <= '2') {
    $count++;
    $the_name = "chkBx";
    $the_value = 'checkbox'.$count;
    if ($count == '1') {
        $its_checked = 'checked'; 
    } else { 
        $its_checked = ''; 
    }
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $the_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $the_value; ?>" <?php echo $its_checked; ?> > 
    <?php
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont"></div><!-- OUTPUTS HERE-->

<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="<?php echo $the_name; ?>"]').on('change',function(){
  var getArrVal = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="<?php echo $the_name; ?>"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).toArray();

  if(getArrVal.length){
    //execute the code
    $('#cont').html(getArrVal.toString());

  } else {
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
    $('#cont').html("At least one value must be checked!");
    return false;

  };
});
</script>
```

#

Update, still having trouble getting the value from the checkboxes ticked into a PHP variable, here is what i have now:

```
<?php
$the_name = "myCheck";
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1.<input type="checkbox" class="<?php echo $the_name; ?>" name="the_name" value="1" checked>
2.<input type="checkbox" class="<?php echo $the_name; ?>" name="the_name" value="2">
3.<input type="checkbox" class="<?php echo $the_name; ?>" name="the_name" value="3"><br/>
<span class="cont" name="bob" value="9999"></span>

<script>
function checkIt() {
    var getArrVal = $(".myCheck:checked").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    if (getArrVal.length) {
        $('.cont').html(getArrVal.join(","));

        var x=$(".cont").text();
        var variablename = $(".cont").val();

    } else {
      $('.cont').html("At least one value must be checked!");
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
      getArrVal=[$(this).val()];
      return false; 
    }
    console.log(getArrVal);
}
$(function() {
  $(".myCheck").on('click',checkIt);
  checkIt();
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you need the array for? Also map returns an array

Comment: You may want to send the output using AJAX to PHP, or may be I did not understood your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the array for?

If you do, you need to keep setting it, both on load and on not allowing the checkbox to be removed

I would personally use a class on the chekcbox which makes a shorter script:

```js
function checkIt() {
    var getArrVal = $(".myCheck:checked").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    if (getArrVal.length) {
      $('#cont').html(getArrVal.join(","));
    } else {
      $('#cont').html("At least one value must be checked!");
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
      getArrVal=[$(this).val()];
      return false; 
    }
    console.log(getArrVal);
}
$(function() {
  $(".myCheck").on('click',checkIt);
  checkIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1.<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="the_name" value="1" checked> 2.<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="the_name" value="2">
3.<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="the_name" value="3"><br/>
<span id="cont"></span>
```

Comment: The checkbox is in a loop so thought the best way would be to put the value in an array to get later.
Would this work in a loop?

Comment: My code does not care how you generate the inputs. To receive an array on the server, one normally gives the `name="somename[]"` when using PHP

Comment: I tried initially to use name="somename[]" but the JS only stored the last value from the loop.

Comment: I cannot guess why - update your question with code. Use a class then name is irrelevant

Comment: Using your code how do I get the class into a php var? Sorry if basic question, still learning.

Comment: reuse the name: `<input type="checkbox" class="<?php echo $the_name; ?>"....` for example

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I need to get the checkboxes ticked into a database to first off need to get into a variable. How do I get the results from the <span class="cont"></span> to a var?

Comment: `var x=$("#cont").text()' if cont is an ID, ".cont" if class and only one span with that class